# Apache HTTPS not working - Windows 10

Tags: apache, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I'm using Apache for development purposes on a Windpows 10 machine and I am having trouble getting HTTPS to work. I downloaded a certificate from sslforfree.com (Part of letsencrypt.org). I followed the instructions at https://geekflare.com/apache-setup-ssl-certificate/. There are no error messages in any of Apache's log files and the access.log file does not change when I attempt to connect to the web server. When I try to connect with Google Chrome from a different network (because HTTPS needs me to use my DNS address), it times out. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4.25 64bit
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

works well under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

but don't load and Apache won't start under Windows 10 Pro 64 bit 1703 with 
Syntax error on line 185 of J:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.25/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1.